# How to create a new many to many reference in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Imagine I have one `user` and one `other` user. The former would like to follow the latter, which I have designed as a many to many relashionship. How can I do it in Javascript? I need something like `user.followers.append(other)`.

Answer (score 2):

In real life you use database connections for that, and you must have a backend already built. But if you're just playing with objects in JS, then you need a `User` class with a `follow` method.

```
function User (params) => {
  const {
    name,
    age,
    friends = []
  } = params

  this.name = name
  this.age = age
  this.friends = friends

  this.follow = (newFriend) => {
    this.friends.append(newFriend)
  }

  this.showFriends = () => {
    console.log(this.friends)
  }
}
```

Then you create two users.

```
const user = new User({
  name: "Joe",
  age: 25
})

const other = new User({
  name: "Francis",
  age: 27
})
```

Then you make one dude follow the other.

```
user.follow(other)
```

Then you can log the user's friends to see what's up.

```
user.showFriends()
```

Comment: I already have a backend with two endpoints: `/users/` and `/posts/`. Should I implement any other endpoint to provide the follow operation? I am trying to use the Single-Page-Application phylosophy, which is why I am trying to manipulate everything from Javascript. Maybe something like `"users/<str:user_id>/follow"`?

Answer (score 0):

Make user.followers as array. So that you can push the userid of the user who is trying to follow them.

Eg:

```
user = {'id': 'current_user_id',
        'followers' : ['user_id_1', 'user_id_2'....]
        };
```